# Plotly sankey digram missing labels

Tags: r, plotly, tidyverse

I want to create a sankey diagram with plotly. In the beginning I had less problems with this compared to networkD3.
My plot looks like this and misses nearly all labels. Why?

[image]

My code is:

> ```
>     fig <- plot_ly(
>   type = "sankey",
>   domain = list(
>     x =  c(0,1),  y =  c(0,1)
>   ),
>   orientation = "h",
>   node = list(
>     label = nodes$postpagename_factor,
>     pad = 15,
>     thickness = 15,
>     line = list(color = "black", width = 0.5)
>   ),
>   link = list(
>     source = automotive_from_to$from,
>     target = automotive_from_to$to,
>     value =  automotive_from_to$value,
>     label =  automotive_from_to$value
>   )
> ) 
> fig <- fig %>% layout(
>   title = "Automotive",
>   font = list(size = 10),
>   xaxis = list(showgrid = F, zeroline = F),
>   yaxis = list(showgrid = F, zeroline = F)
> )
> fig
> ```

automotive_from_to is

> ```
>     structure(list(from = c(2144, 1559, 83, 1559, 1559, 2144, 1558, 
> 1559, 1559, 1563, 1559, 2143, 83, 83, 75, 1953, 1559, 1559, 1559, 
> 2144, 1559, 11, 1559, 1559, 83, 1563, 1559, 1561), to = c(1559, 
> 2144, 2144, 1563, 1953, 11, 1559, 1558, 1561, 1559, 1560, 2147, 
> 2143, 1558, 1953, 1559, 75, 83, 11, 83, 12, 214, 1562, 76, 1957, 
> 1567, 1957, 1559), value = c(1353L, 281L, 1159L, 681L, 343L, 
> 310L, 717L, 151L, 586L, 146L, 260L, 122L, 229L, 205L, 113L, 213L, 
> 152L, 173L, 220L, 125L, 110L, 104L, 111L, 122L, 103L, 112L, 104L, 
> 121L)), row.names = c(NA, -28L), class = "data.frame")
> ```

and nodes is

> ```
> structure(list(postpagename_factor = c(2144, 1559, 1957, 1562, 
> 83, 1563, 1953, 11, 12, 1558, 75, 1561, 1560, 2143, 2147, 76, 
> 214, 1567)), row.names = c(NA, -18L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
> "data.frame"))
> ```

Comment: It seems like plot_ly does not accept missing numbers in ascending order. I changed "from" and "to" to 1,2,3,4,5,....
same in the nodes and arranged it ascending.
I have a labels for nearly all nodes but they appear at the wrong place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is mandatory that the nodes start with 0 and dont't miss numbers in ascending order.
So "from" and "to" are sth like 0,1,2,3,...
You can add a second column in the "nodes" with a real name of the nodes. In my case this is nodes$postpagename_factor